# How to write a self repeating countifs formula on an array?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, countif

I'm trying to do a self replicating countifs.
Basically, if Cell C6:C isn't empty, countifs in 3 ranges according to 3 distinct criteria
My individual cell formula is

```
=if($C6<>"",countifs(data!$K$2:$K,$C6,data!$W$2:$W,"2022",data!$H$2:$H,$C$4),"")
```

But this isn't self replicating and I need to drag it down all the way down. Is there a way to make this a self replicating formula? I know Array formula doesn't quite work well with Contifs

I tried putting it in an IF formula like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"2022"; if(C6:C="","",countifs(data!$K$2:$K,$C6,data!$W$2:$W,"2022",data!$H$2:$H,$C$4))})
```

But I'm getting the result for C6 repeated all over the cells

[Here is an example sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eAaMYJBPVwb9xLFNY3KKVuN_MdJLY1iFN7fL4ORHdCc/edit?usp=sharing) 2022 has the method I tried, 2019 the one suggested here on the bottom (that doesn't work) and 2018 has mu current solution which I'm trying to avoid.

The Transpose method might not work since I have almost 20K rows in the "data" sheet.

Thank you.

Comment: Share a sample workbook and show your input and desired output?

Comment: sample workbook updated

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data it is hard to advise. But if you want to result in array fashion means spill results automatically to each cell in resulting column then can try below formula-

```
=Arrayformula(IF(Data!$K$2:$K="",,COUNTIFS(Data!$K$2:$K,$C6,Data!$W$2:$W,2022,Data!$H$2:$H,$C$4, ROW(Data!$K$2:$K), "<="&ROW(Data!$K$2:$K))))
```

Comment: I updated a sample workbook, your solution did not work.

Comment: @Borrris See your sheet1 `C7` cell formula.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I should have made clear that Col k has no numbers, just names.
Once I changed it from user 1, user 2, user 3 to names (John doe etc) your solution no longer works.

Comment: In case of `Countifs()` data range and criteria range must be same. Check the current formula now.

Comment: Check this formula `=Arrayformula(IF(B7:B807="",,COUNTIFS(data!$K$2:$K802,B7:B807,data!$W$2:$W802,$C$6,data!$H$2:$H802,$B$5)))`

Answer (score 0):

My IF formula was actually correct, I just forgot to make it run on C6:C instead of just C6

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"2022"; if(C6:C="","",countifs(data!$K$2:$K,$C6,data!$W$2:$W,"2022",data!$H$2:$H,$C$4))})
```

This is the one that works:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({"2022"; if(C6:C="","",countifs(data!$K$2:$K,$C6:C,data!$W$2:$W,"2022",data!$H$2:$H,$C$4))})`